# The iOS native app did not scroll to the target element when using Robot Framework

Tags: ios, automation, robotframework, ui-automation, appium-ios

I am currently utilizing the Robot Framework to create automation scripts for native iOS applications. Throughout the automation process, I have been relying on accessibility IDs to interact with elements within the application. However, I have encountered challenges when attempting to scroll to a particular element.

I have used built-in scroll commands (scroll, scroll up, and scroll down) provided by the Robot Framework scroll the application screen but sometimes bypass the specific element I need to interact with. Instead, they move further up or down, missing the target element.

I have used Used version
iOS version - 15, and
Appium Version - 2.0.0

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code you are using and the UI? Without it, it will be hard to help.